# using same mysql user with many databases

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb

As we know that in order to connect **WP** with database we should to define **mysql username** and password in wp-config.php, so at that point i have a question regarding security or ( some sort of connecting error ):

> **it is good practice using same mysql user with many databases**

one thing is that i haven't seen any trouble regarding this but was thinking someday it will come :) hope you understand
well thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's really not good practise, but this depends on how you're accessing the other databases.

For example, I have a server that hosts 10+ different Wordpress sites.

I have two options for connecting to the databases:

1. Use the *root* login in all my wp-config.php files as it's easier
2. Create a user and logins associated with each database for each site

Number 1 is useful when I'm developing *locally*/on a virtual machine as the databases aren't accessible to the outside world.

Number 2 is definitely the best practise when you're running a *live server* with multiple databases. At most if your password does get compromised you're only exposing one database.